# jsfiddle works in FireFox, Chrome but not IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/ZgNuC/4/). It works fine in Chrome and FireFox, but I get this error when running it in IE8:

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 244
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://jsfiddle.net/js/Actions.js
```

I added the code from this JSFiddle to my site and I'm seeing the same issue with IE8. Do I have to add something specific to get it working in IE8?

Thanks

Comment: I always have trouble using the "run" button on jsFiddle with IE8. I just don't use that browser there anymore.

Comment: I don't see that error in IE9 running in IE8 mode.  **Edit:** Yes, I do... after I click "Run".

Comment: Still does not work in IE8. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of jsFiddle's scripts contains an error.  It is expecting the element to have already been extended by MooTools, but it's not.  If I knew how, I'd tell the jsFiddle devs that they need to wrap `e.target` in a call to `$()`:

Line 244 of http://jsfiddle.net/js/Actions.js:

```
if (e && $(e.target).getParent().get('id') == 'm') {
```

**Edit:** As a work around, add this bookmarklet to your links bar and click it once when the page loads.  It will get the run button in a state where the error won't occur anymore.

```
javascript: $$("#run > span"); void 0;
```

Another work around is to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> instead of clicking the "run" button.

While we're on the topic of making jsFiddle behave with IE through bookmarklets, here's one I use to get the jsFiddle toolbar back in view after it goes all wonky when I paste something into the script editor pane:

```
javascript: document.body.scrollIntoView(); void 0;
```

There's no reason you couldn't combine those into one - neither would have any ill effect on the other:

```
javascript: document.body.scrollIntoView(); $$("#run > span"); void 0;
```

Comment: I added a link to this thread over here... https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-docs-alpha/issues/108

Comment: It is right - it's our fault. This is fixed in dev version - we will push the changes to the life server soon.

Comment: doesn't look like this change has been pushed yet?  JSFiddle still doesn't load on IE8, compatibility or not.  Normally I wouldn't really care, but I'm limited to IE8 in my current corporate environment.

Comment: @heiserman - No, this was fixed over a year ago. What you're seeing today must be a new regression. JSFiddle was recently updated, so that recent update is probably to blame.

Answer (score 3):

It's not your script. I just ran JSFiddle completely empty with jQuery version you had selected and all the different load settings.

You get the error every time, even if you have no javascript in your window at all.

Comment: Interesting. I'm getting a similar error in IE8 from the jQuery when I put that code on my site. If I strip out the jQuery, I don't see the IE8 error.